# In a DotNetNuke site how do I bypass a 404 error?

Tags: http-status-code-404, dotnetnuke

I have a site -- example.com. It has static pages -- example.com/signup, example.com/faq, etc.

However, I want to be able to have "example.com/some-search-term". Of course, there is no page "some-search-term".

I tried installing a custom module on the 404 error page that would take the query string and display some info based on that search criteria. However, I still get a 404 error "HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://example.com/some-search-term." and the page is blank.

I can debug my module when the 404 page is triggered and see that everything is working fine but the final results are not displayed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a different way.

DNN provides a default 404 page. I simply added a custom module that evaluates the status code on Page_Load():

```
        _rcode = Response.StatusCode;
        if (_rcode == 404) //we're on our 404 page
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
        }
```

The module then does a few database lookups on the query string to see if there are any matches. If there are, it redirects to the appropriate page. If nothing matches, then I generate a 404 error.

I was trying to keep everything on the 404 page but I couldn't. Since the page "example.com/some-search-term" doesn't actually exist, some page components aren't available -- IsPostBack, ViewState, Session, etc. -- so it was difficult to generate a page that worked. Even setting the Response.StatusCode to 200 did not work.

Ultimately, I was trying to prevent google from seeing a 404 error unless I wanted it to. This seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this I would suggest using IIS rewrite rules or rewritemaps.  You can do this via the web.config or separate files that the web.config points to.  If you setup a redirect for each term, you'll be good to go.

EG: in `Web.config`

```
<rewrite>
  <rewriteMaps configSource="fmrewrites.config" />
  <rules configSource="fmrules.config" />
</rewrite>
```

And within the `fmrewrites.congig`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rewriteMaps>
  <rewriteMap name="FmRedirects">
    <add key="www.siteexample.com/," value="https://www.siteexample.com/" />
  </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

Or within the `fmrules.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="FmRewrites" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{FmRedirects:{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

You can read up on a lot of this [via MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).